# How to manipulate forms in Angular Dart?

Tags: dart, angular-dart

I'm can't find any doc that explains how to manipulates forms in Angular Dart.

I've got the following code in `my_component.html`:

```dart
<form name="form" ng-submit="comp.save()">
  <input type="text" required ng-model="comp.user.firstname">
  <input type="text" required ng-model="comp.user.lastname">
  <button ng-disabled="form.invalid">Save</button>
</form>
```

And the following one in `my_component.dart`:

```dart
@NgComponent(
  selector    : 'my-component',
  templateUrl : 'my_component.html',
  publishAs   : 'comp'
)
class MyComponent {

  @NgTwoWay('user')
  User user;

  @NgTwoWay('form')
  NgForm form;

  MyComponent() {};

  void save() {
    print(form);
  }

}
```

The validation works well, but when clicking on the button, the `print(form)` statement always prints `null`.

Any idea?

Thanks

Comment: Than you @gunter-zochbauer for the formatting

Comment: The code is just so much easier to read. Was that what you were looking for?

Comment: I couldn't find how to do it by myself. Still got a few questions :)

Comment: It's a bit tricky. You need a comment `<!-- language: lang-dart -->` or `<!-- language-all: lang-dart -->` (for all following code blocks) in the first column, it must be written exactly like shown. One space more or less and it doesn't work. It needs an empty line before and afterwards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess this is what you want:

```dart
class MyComponent {
  @NgTwoWay('user')
  User user = new User();

  Scope scope;

  MyComponent(this.scope) {}

  void save() {
    var form = (scope.context['form'] as NgForm);
    print(form.invalid);
  }
}
```

Comment: Why can't I just use a `@NgTwoWay('form') NgForm form`? Is this because the forms have not been fully implemented yet?

Comment: @NgTwoWay('form')` is to bind the value of the attribute `form` to the field but there is no attribute 'form' on your element. I just looked at the code of NgForm and what it does is to assign itself to the scope under the name assigned to the `name` attribute. I haven't uses it myself yet.

Comment: `form.controls` is always an empty map and `{{form.valid}}` and `{{form.invalid}}` are always `null`. It seems that I'm the only one trying to use forms with Angular Dart :)

Comment: I tried it before posting and it worked. There must be something wrong. (I forgot to change MyForm back to MyComponent as you saw because I already had a MyComponent in the app where I tried it)

Comment: What Angular version do you use? (I tried with 0.9.9) Also `ng-disabled='form.invalid'` worked fine.

Comment: I'm using 0.9.9 too. I've created a new project and everything works as expected. Thank you for your help!